# Cannot map from public property to public virtual property

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a custom class:

```
public class Class1 {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public MFileType DefaultFileType { get; set; }
}
```

that I'm trying to map to:

```
public class Class2 {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual FileType DefaultFileType { get; set; }
}
```

I know that I can ignore the FileType in the ForMember() method.

But is it possible to map Class1 to Class2 for the MFileType/FileType properties?

I tried using:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FileType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MFileType));
```

but this doesn't work.  The Class2 file was generated by a code tool so I can't change that.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is `MFileType` a child type of `FileType`? If not, did you try creating a map for `MFileType` to `FileType`?

Comment: No, I think that FileType is a child type of MFileType.

Comment: Please check what the relation is between `FileType` and `MFileType`. It is kind of important to know whether `FileType` is a child of `MFileType` or `MFileType` is a child of `FileType` (huge difference!).

Comment: Yes, MFileType is a child type of FileType.  I thought that the CreateMap *did* map do that.  Since it appears that I didn't do that, how would I map MFileType to FileType?

Comment: For me it works, see my code [**here**](http://pastebin.com/6AVYA0gg) (please note to add the AutoMapper reference or install it through Nuget!). Note that my "ForMember" method call is a little different, but normally you shouldn't be able to compile your code anyway due to the "typo" (`dest.FileType` and not `dest.DefaultFileType`).

Comment: Arrrgh!!! Websense filtering not letting me see it.  I'll have to postpone this pleasure for a few hours until I get home.  Meanwhile, if you haven't seen this, this would also work:  http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers

Comment: I uploaded the code to my own domain: http://hdmd.be/program.cs.html

Comment: Now how do you get credit for this answer when there are "no responses"?

Comment: I added an answer (distilled an answer out of the comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, `MFileType` is a child type of (inherits) `FileType`. Looking at your code, your mapping doesn't seem to be correct, as you try to map `dest.DefaultFileType` (and not `dest.FileType`) given the provided classes. If you fix this, it should work, as demonstrated in the demo code below.

Please note, you should add a reference to the AutoMapper library or simply install it through Nuget.

```
class FileType
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
class MFileType : FileType
{
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}

class Class1
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public MFileType DefaultFileType { get; set; }
}
class Class2
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual FileType DefaultFileType { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DefaultFileType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DefaultFileType));

        var class1 = new Class1() { Id = "class1", DefaultFileType = new MFileType() { MyProperty = 1, MyProperty2 = 2 } };
        var class2 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Class2>(class1);

        Console.WriteLine("class2.Id = " + class2.Id);
        // If below it says "False", it mapped correctly
        Console.WriteLine("class2.DefaultFileType == null = " + class2.DefaultFileType == null);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the late add.  I could've sworn that I tagged this as the correct answer.

Comment: 2 years, nearly 500 views, yet no up-vote. Worth an up-vote just for the effort. Thanks anyway, twas helpful